# How does google automatically create 3D cityscapes?

Tags: algorithms, 3d

In the last years, Google models not only are major cities, but also suburban and rural areas ([google video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6Douyfa7l8))

I read that there are some tridimensional model building algorithm [here](https://googleblog.blogspot.it/2012/06/never-ending-quest-for-perfect-map.html).

How could such algoithm work? Stereovision? Multiple photos?

Comment: @ChristianClason Can you move it through StackExchange websites or should I? Thanks :)

Comment: Only moderators can do that; I flagged your question so they can take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They basically use 3D reconstruction based on ground and sometimes aerial footage of places, generally using stereo cameras. With this footage, they build a 3D point cloud based on the images to do the reconstruction (which is particularly trivial for a stereo setup).

I was told that if the reconstruction isn't good enough for more important/well known landmarks, they will have someone create a better 3D model in some CAD software. But I do think most of what they have, impressively, is done algorithmically based on 3D point clouds and potentially some other things I am unaware of (homographies maybe?).

Comment: My friend recently did a descriptively named PhD: "From images to point clouds: practical considerations for three-dimensional computer vision" Daniel Herrera Castro, dissertation (2015) Acta Univ Oul C 536. http://urn.fi/urn:isbn:9789526208534

Answer (score 0):

Not really a good answer, but I do know that [Ben Appleton](http://research.google.com/pubs/author1328.html) used to be in this part of Google, and his research interests include [**Embedded Voxel Colouring.**](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub40353.html)

Note: I am not sure whether Google used this work in their Google Maps generation.

Comment: I think the Sydney office works on google maps so it may well be used. (Actually Ben got me an interview with google just as I was about to start my PhD.)

Comment: @geometrikal cool! I was in the same research group as Ben when he was doing his PhD at UQ.

Comment: Yes I had you as a lecturer I think?  (Ross Marchant, you may remember me)

Comment: @geometrikal of course! I remember! Good to hear you're still kicking around. :-)